# How to Merge Multiple Continuous Git branches?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I am on branch `branch-1`. I did some changes and made 5 commits and opened a PR on GitHub repo.

Now, I did `git checkout -b branch-2`. Then I did some improvements and made 5 more commits. (notice that there are total 10 commits now in branch-2)

Now, I did `git checkout -b branch-3`. Then I did some improvements and made 5 more commits. (notice that there are total 15 commits now in branch-3)

Now, I did `git checkout -b branch-4`. Then I did some improvements and made 5 more commits. (notice that there are total 20 commits now in branch-4)

Now, There are 4 different PRs on GitHub repo corresponding to 4 branches.

Now, Here are some of my questions:-

1. I did `git checkout branch-2` and done some more improvements and committed them. now, how can I bring those changes back to `branch-3` and `branch-4`?
2. Is there any other efficient way to do work in this case? I mean when you have to create small PRs on Github repo but all new branches depend on previous branches.

   Thanks :)

Comment: You can merge any 2 branches, so now `branch-2` can be merged into `branch-3` and `branch-4` to get those changes there too.

Comment: As for the efficient way, branches represent features, if you diverge from one branch, to implement some separate feature, I would suggest to merge back into that branch, This will keep everything in the right order.

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that while `branch-2` does contain all the commits that are also in `branch-1`, `branch-1` probably has far more than 5 commits: it also has most or all of the commits that are in `master` and/or `develop` and/or most other branches. All of this stems from the fact that in Git, branches always contain *all* the history leading to the branch-tip.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create a new PR from a branch that depends on another PR.
It makes it harder for the maintainer to review.
If he looks at `branch-2` before `branch-1`,
he will see all the changes in both,
which might be overwhelming all at once.
And then, after reviewing `branch-2` if he opens `branch-1`,
he will waste his time reading stuff he has already reviewed.

If you want to create a new PR from a branch that depends on another PR,
either wait until the first PR is merged,
or consider deleting the first PR.
This is still not a great option,
because if you create a lot of PRs and then delete them to supersede by another PR,
that can be a lot of noise.

Also ask yourself if these branches need to depend on each other.
If not, then start new branches from `origin/master`,
not from a pending PR.

If `branch-1` received comments after you already started work on `branch-2` which depends on `branch-1`, not a problem. Implement the requested improvements in `branch-1`, and once accepted, merge or rebase into `branch-2`.
After `branch-1` is accepted,
when you create the PR for `branch-2`,
the changes in `branch-1`, including the corrections,
will not be visible anymore,
the reviewer will see only the changes of `branch-2`.

Comment: As an addendum to this, I've *rejected* entire PRs that have done this kind of thing.  You don't want to go any more than one or two deep if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

1: You can do it with merge or with rebase. In such linear case I prefer rebase.

```
git rebase branch-2 branch-1
git rebase branch-3 branch-2
git rebase branch-4 branch-3
```

2. Create a new PR after the previous is accepted.